# SQL Query on combining 2 columns

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with 2 columns both having numbers

```
Col1       Col2
23          56
23          57     
24          56
24          57
```

expected o/p

```
Col1
23
56
24
57
```

Scenario 2

```
Col1        Col2
23           56
23           57
```

expected o/p

```
23
56
```

Please help with a simple sql query.

Comment: explain the output of scenario 2

Comment: Please tag the DBMS. Also, why is scenario2 only returning 56 and not 57?

Comment: How di you get `23 , 56` ?

Comment: I want first encountered pair. Any one would do (23,56 or 23,57)

Comment: Simple query? Perhaps it is, but the scenario isn't very clear...

Comment: In the first scenario I need one pair in each set. (23-56,24-57 or vice versa 23-57,24-56) In the second scenario , any one pair is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1

```
select Col1
from Mytable
union            -- union will ensure distinct rows selected
select Col2
from Mytable
```

Comment: Thank you. I want a single query for both the scenarios. Since the table can have both types of data